# force a file download with PHP, headers

Tags: php, mysql, download, readfile

I am returning a table with corresponding "download" links, which are assigned by id's from my database.  User clicks on "download" and gets a notification that they will begin a file download.  Right now I can click on "download" and the file I download is not the desired file, it is an echo of the php page.

Here is the current code:

Profile.php

```
   <?php if (isset($_POST['query']))
   {
   require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); //Connect to the db

    // Make the query
   $genre = $_POST['select_genre'];
   $length = $_POST['select_length'];

    $upviews = "UPDATE upload
                SET views = views + 1
                WHERE genre = '$genre' AND length = '$length'";
    $runviewupdate = mysqli_query ($dbc, $upviews);


    $q = "SELECT upload_id, title, genre, length, created
        FROM upload
        WHERE genre = '$genre' AND length = '$length'
        ORDER BY created DESC, title DESC";


    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query

    if($r)
    {
        // If it ran okay, display the records
        echo '<table align="center"
            cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"
            width="75%">
           <tr><td align="left"><b>Title</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Genre</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Pages</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Submitted</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Download</b></td>';

        // Fetch and print all the records:

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            echo '<tr><td align="left">' .
            $row['title'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            . $row['genre'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            . $row['length'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            . $row['created'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            //. $row['views'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            . "<a href='newpub_profile.php?id={$row['upload_id']}'>Download</a></td>" . '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>'; // Close the table

        mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources
    }
    else // If it did not run okay
    {
        // Public Message:

        echo '<p class="error">Your submissions could not be retrieved.  We
            apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';

        // Debugging message:

        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

    } // End of if ($r) IF.



}

//END DOWNLOAD HANDLER ******************************************************


    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection




                    // Make sure an ID was passed DOWNLOAD HANDLER *******
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Get the ID
    $id = intval($_GET['id']); //var_dump($id);

    require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); //Connect to the db

// Fetch the file information
        $downloadq = "
            SELECT `file_type`, `size`, `title`, 'content', 'upload_id'
            FROM `upload`
            WHERE `upload_id` =".$id;
        $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $downloadq); // Run the query


        if($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                //var_dump($row);

                $place = './uploads/'.$_SESSION_['email'].'/';
                $thefile = $place.$row['title'];

                require('./download.php');
                filedownload();


                // Print headers
              // header("Content-Type: application/msword");
              // header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
              // header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['title']);
              // header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
              // readfile($thefile);



                // Print data
                //echo (stripslashes($row['content']));



                exit;


            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No such ID.';
            }

            // Free the mysqli resources
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbc->error}</pre>";
        }
        mysqli_close($dbc);



    }

                    ?>
```

download.php

```
<?PHP

function filedownload()
{
               header("Content-Type: application/msword");
               header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
               header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['title']);
               header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
               readfile($thefile, 1);

}
               ?>
```

The "download" link from the table corresponds correctly to the id for the file in the database. Clicking "download" downloads a file called profile.php and contains my php and html markup. Thanks in advance, this has me stumped.

Comment: try echoing $thefile in you filedownload function to see that it has the correct filename, try passing the filename and $row array in, instead of relying on global vars

Comment: before you do anything else with this code, read about up about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and FIX YOUR CODE, before your server gets pwn3d.

Comment: Yes, I will use bound parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting

```
global $row, $thefile;
```

as a first line inside your filedownload()-function. I notice you're trying to use variables from outside this function.

Comment: I tried this.  The result is that I now download a file with the correct title as it corresponds to my database.  However, the contents of the file is the html markup from my profile page, complete with textboxes and headers.

Comment: Noticed it just now: your download-link refers to a file called `newpub_profile.php`. Is that the bottom section of the upper code?

Comment: Overlooked that link. newpub_profile.php is the name of the file that contains the first block of code above, I referred to it as "profile.php". Should this link be pointing directly to download.php instead?